# Port not open when using an SSH tunnel

Tags: macos, port-forwarding, ssh-tunnel

```
ssh -N -L 1982:123.456.789.123:22 user@123.456.789.123
```

That's what I'm doing so on `Box1` so that it listens on port 1982 and passes that along to port 22 of `123.456.789.123`. When I do a `netstat -a | egrep 'Proto|LISTEN'`, it shows:

```
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State
tcp        0      0 localhost:1982          *:*                     LISTEN
tcp        0      0 *:ssh                   *:*                     LISTEN
tcp6       0      0 ip6-localhost:1982      [::]:*                  LISTEN
tcp6       0      0 [::]:ssh                [::]:*                  LISTEN
```

So it is listening on port 1982. When I go to my local machine and try to connect to `Box1` via Port 1982, it says the port is closed. What can I do to make it listen?

Comment: Could there be a firewall between local and Box1?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Box1 only listens on 1982 on the loopback interface. You cant use it to route traffic from other boxes with that setup.

**EDIT:**

You see that because it says `localhost` in your question on the line:

`tcp        0      0 localhost:1982          *:*                     LISTEN`

If you instead set the binding address too you should get the result you are after, eg:

`ssh -N -L 0.0.0.0:1982:123.456.789.123:22 user@123.456.789.123`

You see the syntax for local port forwards in the [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/ssh) if you want to take a closer look at it.

Comment: care to include what that output would look like depending on whether it's on loopback vs on "any"? (so that your answer shows how to determine that)

Comment: @barlop I hope my edit clarifies both how to determine what was wrong and also how to fix the problem.

Comment: +1 yes pretty good, I hadn't noticed that in the netstat results 'cos i'm used to windows netstat.  With ssh you can also do `*:` as a shorthand for 0.0.0.0: